# Get the latest date folder

Tags: kdb

I have many date folders under path:`/var/tmp/`

```
2018.07.04
2018.07.05
2018.07.06
2018.07.07
2018.07.08
2018.07.09
```

And I want to get latest date folder`[ 2018.07.09]` from above folders.how  should i do?

Comment: is this a partitioned database?

Comment: It`s for kdb , I want to achieve it by q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if the folders are in chronological older:

```
-1#(!:)hsym`$"/var/tmp"
```

Answer (score 3):

If its KDB partitioned database you can simply load  it and run following command:

```
q) \l /var/tmp
q) max date
```

If its normal folder you can try:

Edit: Changes based on Jonathon comments:

```
 q) max "D"$string key `:/var/tmp
```

Comment: Probably don't need to filter with the `where`, non-date filenames will cast to `0Nd` so `max` should still work